# My APK is 118MB... I just need some ideas on how to reduce it's size?

Tags: android, apk, filesize

I'm developing an android app that contains a large library of videos that can be viewed... there's about 30 videos in the res/raw folder, I'm guessing that's the cause of the huge apk file size?

Does anyone have any tips on how to reduce it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the files as online content. The first time the app starts, it checks for availability of all files. If they are not there, a download begins, or the user is prompted to find a data-connection. Possibly warn the user that this is semi-big, so users on a plan can use WiFi.

Comment: How about should I go about providing the videos as online content?  Should I upload them somewhere and have it individually download each file upon start up if they don't exist?  I'm not entirely sure how to do what you mentioned above lol, thanks!

Comment: You should first find a location (webserver or something). Lets say `http://yourlocation.com/yourfiles/`. Then you can check your filelist you have defined for missing files on the device: if there is a missing file, you can download it in code.

Comment: Ok I think I understand.  I'll find that and try to write up a test program to download files in java.  Thanks man!

Comment: So just another question, I wrote a function to download files but my only concern is the actual path.  Could I name it to be sdcard/videoz/x.mp4?  I'm assuming the root path would always be sdcard.

Comment: Check out this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html . I would try if there is external storage first and then obtain a directory (see that link, there are methods for that). If not available, use internal storage, and you'll get a directory from the system too. There are examples in that link.

Comment: Isn't internal storage only around 38 mb sometimes?  I would most definitely want to use external storage.  Is there a case where an android phone has terrible internal storage or no sd card?

Comment: Internal storage depends on the phone, and not all phones have an sd-card (didn't the nexus skip that feature?). Anyway, you can check for availalility of external storage, so why not do that for the case that the user doesn't have any. And if there is only internal you can warn them about what they are to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are kind of limited:

1. Encode the videos at a lower quality or with a more compact encoding
2. Get rid of the videos from the .apk file and have the app download them as needed from a web site
3. Get rid of the videos from the .apk file and redesign your app to do without them

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same way Gameloft does with their 500mb+ games: Give/sell a 200k or similar very lightweight downloading program and then download all the assets. It's common and users understand this.

Remember, online only content for cellphones is a hard sell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Expansion Files
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html